# C++/CLI: SYSTEMTIME Programming Error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, if-statement, c++-cli, int, systemtime

I'm trying to make a little alert system to do something (IDK what I want yet) when a certain time arrives. However, I'm getting all these errors when I run that code in a WinForm after some brief changes. But this code (unchanged) worked in my empty project! I have the snippet below:

```
int checktime ()
{
    SYSTEMTIME time;
    GetLocalTime( &time );
    int hour = time.wHour;
    int minute = time.wMinute;
    if (hour > 12) hour -= 12;
    if hour == 8
    {
        this->progressBar1->PerformStep();
    }
}
```

As always, I would appreciate any help or suggestions available. Thanks!

Comment: You say "I'm getting all these errors" but you don't say what the errors are.  We are not psychic.

Comment: @John But I knew you were going to say that...

Comment: Yeah, well, we aren't psychic, but we are predictable.  :)

Comment: @Francis Were you able to get it working?

Comment: OK, the errors are as follows: `error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'hour'` and `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'` Please help...

Comment: All right, I think I got my code now! See what Ben posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if hour == 8
```

That's not valid C++ or C++/CLI.  The parentheses in an `if` statement are not optional.

And why aren't you using .NET `System::DateTime::Now`?  That whole function could be:

```
int checktime ()
{
   int hour = System::DateTime::Now.Hour;
   if (hour == 8 || hour == 20)
    this->progressBar1->PerformStep();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) object to keep track of the passing time.

In the designer, drag a timer over from the toolbox onto your form, or instantiate one in the code.  You can set the duration (using the `interval` member), and with each "tick", the system raises an event, and you can perform an action.

It's nice because it's almost like having another thread keeping track in the background.

Comment: Inside the timer tick, you might still need to inspect the current time.  This snippet doesn't appear to be waiting for a particular time.

Comment: @Ben I agree that a check of the current time would be a good idea, if only for correcting any drift in the interval between the tics.  My impression was that the OP was trying for 8am (edit: or 8pm also, as you have pointed out), though the code is not specific enough.